# show logged in content in the best way

Tags: javascript, php

if the user is not login then redirect him to log in page, else show logged in content. But my logged in content is huge, should I just paste it in between this block of code :

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
// here
}
```

is this the usual way you guys do it? that is tons of markup

Comment: create a separate file with tone of markup and redirect to that page in if condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){
  header('Location:home.php');//Redirecting to a page containing huge data to show after succesfull login
}
else{
  header('Location:login.php');//Redirecting to login page
}
```

Where `home.php` is the file containg huge data you want to show after login.

Comment: in home.php can use the session set in register page?

Comment: yes sure.You can do it either in home.php or in if condition.

Comment: This'll work great. Keep in mind that you can't output any data or change the header in any way before you make the redirect, so keep this as high up as possible. Also, don't forget to check if the user is logged in in home.php as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just do as you've written.

```
if (!isSet($_SESSION['logged_in'])) {
    //redirect
}
//rest of the content
```

You don't need an extra `if` now and can display/include your content easily.